# string manipulation, data wrangling, regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a `.txt` file of 3 million rows. The file contains data that looks like this:

```
# RSYNC: 0 1 1 0 512 0
#$SOA 5m localhost. hostmaster.localhost. 1906022338 1h 10m 5d 1s
# random_number_ofspaces_before_this text $TTL 60s
#more random information
:127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
test
:127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.0-0m5tk.com
.0-1-hub.com
.zzzy1129.cn
:127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.0-il.ml
.005verf-desj.com
.01accesfunds.com
```

In the above data, there is a code associated with all domains listed beneath it. 
I want to turn the above data into a format that can be loaded into a HiveQL/SQL. The HiveQL table should look like:

```
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|    domain_name     | period_count | parsed_code |                      raw_code                       |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| test               |            0 | 127.0.1.2   |  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .0-0m5tk.com       |            2 | 127.0.1.2   |  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .0-1-hub.com       |            2 | 127.0.1.2   |  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .zzzy1129.cn       |            2 | 127.0.1.2   |  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .0-il.ml           |            2 | 127.0.1.4   |  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .005verf-desj.com  |            2 | 127.0.1.4   |  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .01accesfunds.com  |            2 | 127.0.1.4   |  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

***Please note that I do not want the vertical bars in any output. They are just to make the above look like a table***

I'm guessing that creating a HiveQL table like the above will involve converting the `.txt` into a `.csv` or a Pandas data frame. If creating a `.csv`, then the `.csv` would probably look like:

```
domain_name,period_count,parsed_code,raw_code
test,0,127.0.1.2,:127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.0-0m5tk.com,2,127.0.1.2,:127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.0-1-hub.com,2,127.0.1.2,:127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.zzzy1129.cn,2,127.0.1.2,:127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.0-il.ml,2,127.0.1.4,:127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.005verf-desj.com,2,127.0.1.4,:127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.01accesfunds.com,2,127.0.1.4,:127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
```

I'd be interested in a Python solution, but lack familiarity with the packages and functions necessary to complete the above data wrangling steps. I'm looking for a complete solution, or code tidbits to construct my own solution. I'm guessing regular expressions will be needed to identify the "category" or "code" line in the raw data. They always start with ":127.0.1." I'd also like to parse the code out to create a `parsed_code` column, and a `period_count` column that counts the number of periods in the `domain_name` string. For testing purposes, please create a `.txt` of the sample data I have provided at the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of how you want to format in the end, I suppose the first step is to separate the `domain_name` and `code`. That part is pure python

```
rows = []
code = None
parsed_code = None
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line.startswith(':127'):
            code = line
            parsed_code = line.split(':')[1]
            continue
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        period_count = line.count('.')                    
        rows.append((line,period_count,parsed_code, code))
```

Just for illustration, you can use `pandas` to format the data nicely as tables, which might help if you want to pipe this to SQL, but it's not absolutely necessary. Post-processing of strings are also quite straightforward in `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['domain_name', 'period_count', 'parsed_code',  'raw_code'])
print (df)
```

prints this:

```
         domain_name  period_count parsed_code                                           raw_code
0               test             0   127.0.1.2  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...
1       .0-0m5tk.com             2   127.0.1.2  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...
2       .0-1-hub.com             2   127.0.1.2  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...
3       .zzzy1129.cn             2   127.0.1.2  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...
4           .0-il.ml             2   127.0.1.4  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...
5  .005verf-desj.com             2   127.0.1.4  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...
6  .01accesfunds.com             2   127.0.1.4  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...
```

Comment: Why add pandas? That can be done with just the standard library.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. How do you read the `.txt`? I tried: `file = open('example_filename.txt', 'r')` and `file = open('dbl-sr-2019-06-02T23_38_27Z.txt', 'w')`. `print (df)` shows:                                          `domain_name  code
0  <open file 'dbl-sr-2019-06-02T23_38_27Z.txt', ...  None`

Comment: @Tim: that's exactly why I said it's just for illustration, and it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @AdityaSantoso your solution works. is it possible to update your solution such that it provides two additional columns? i added details on those additional columns in my original post. thanks

Comment: @user2205916: added. But honestly they are all standard python string manipulation. It might be worth going through them yourself to get more familiarity of python standard library

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this with the Python standard library.

```
HEADER = "domain_name | code"    

# Open files
with open("input.txt") as f_in, open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
    # Write header
    print(HEADER, file=f_out)
    print("-" * len(HEADER), file=f_out)

    # Parse file and output in correct format
    code = None
    for line in f_in:
        if line.startswith("#"):
            # Ignore comments
            continue
        if line.endswith("$"):
            # Store line as the current "code"
            code = line
        else:
            # Write these domain_name entries into the 
            # output file separated by ' | '
            print(line, code, sep=" | ", file=f_out)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. 

  `File "<ipython-input-5-c0328c406c45>", line 6
    print(HEADER, file=f_out)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7? if so you will need to add `from __future__ import print_function`